# How does jest allow mutation of modules?

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules, transpiler, babel-jest

In this question that I asked here:

[Why does mutating a module update the reference if calling that module from another module, but not if calling from itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54318830/why-does-mutating-a-module-update-the-reference-if-calling-that-module-from-anot)

I'm asking about the nature of module mutation.

However as it it turns out, ES6 modules can't actually be mutated - all of their properties are treated as constants. ([See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54321280/1068446))

But somehow - when Jest tests modules - they can be mutated, and that's how Jest allows for mocking.

How is this happening?

I imagine that it's a babel plugin that that's running - transpiling the module to CommonJS modules? Is there any documentation about this?

Is there a way to view the transpiled code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ES6 modules can't actually be mutated - all of their properties are treated as constants.

Interesting.  You're right, even something as simple as this:

```js
import * as lib from "./lib";  // import an ES6 module
const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'someFunc');  // spy on someFunc
```

...technically shouldn't be allowed since `jest.spyOn` [replaces the method on the object with a spy](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/d7ca8b23acf2fdd1d070496efb2b2709644a6f4f/packages/jest-mock/src/index.js#L805-L811) and `lib.someFunc` should be a binding to `someFunc` in the ES6 module.

---

> But somehow - when Jest tests modules - they can be mutated, and that's how Jest allows for mocking.
>
> How is this happening?

They can only be mutated because `Jest` isn't actually using ES6 modules.

(I guess for completeness it *might* be possible to run `Jest` using actual ES6 modules by using `Node`'s [experimental support for ES6 Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_ecmascript_modules) but I haven't tried).

---

> I imagine that it's a babel plugin that that's running - transpiling the module...Is there any documentation about this?

["`babel-jest` is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project.  To avoid this behavior, you can explicitly reset the `transform` configuration option"](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel).

So by default `Jest` will use `babel-jest` which transpiles the source code using `babel` (and does a few other things like [hoisting calls to `jest.mock`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-jest-hoist#babel-plugin-jest-hoist)).

Note that `Jest` can be also be configured using [`transform`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-string) which maps "regular expressions to paths to transformers".

---

> Is there a way to view the transpiled code?

Yes.  Transformations are done in `jest-runtime` [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/d7ca8b23acf2fdd1d070496efb2b2709644a6f4f/packages/jest-runtime/src/ScriptTransformer.js#L244-L246) and the output is saved to a cache [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/d7ca8b23acf2fdd1d070496efb2b2709644a6f4f/packages/jest-runtime/src/ScriptTransformer.js#L286).

The easiest way to look at the transpiled code is to view the cache.

You can do that by running `Jest` with the [`--showConfig`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#showconfig) option which will output the `config` used when running `Jest`.  The cache location can be found by looking at the value of "cacheDirectory".

Then run `Jest` with the [`--clearCache`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#clearcache) option to clear out the cache.

Finally, run `Jest` normally and the cache directory will contain the transpiled code for your project.

---

**Example**

The latest `Jest` (v24) will transpile this code:

```js
// lib.js
export const someFunc = () => 1;


// code.js
import { someFunc } from './lib';
export const func = () => someFunc() + 1;


// code.test.js
import { func } from './code';
import * as lib from './lib';

test('func', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'someFunc');
  func();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // SUCCESS
});
```

...to this:

```js
// lib.js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.someFunc = void 0;
const someFunc = () => 1;
exports.someFunc = someFunc;


// code.js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.func = void 0;
var _lib = require("./lib");
const func = () => (0, _lib.someFunc)() + 1;
exports.func = func;


// code.test.js
"use strict";
var _code = require("./code");
var lib = _interopRequireWildcard(require("./lib"));
function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } else { var newObj = {}; if (obj != null) { for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) { var desc = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : {}; if (desc.get || desc.set) { Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc); } else { newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } } } newObj.default = obj; return newObj; } }
test('func', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(lib, 'someFunc');
  (0, _code.func)();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled(); // SUCCESS
});
```

The `import * as lib from 'lib';` line gets handled by `_interopRequireWildcard` which uses `require` under the hood.

Every call to `require` ["will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file"](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching) so `code.js` and `code.test.js` are getting the same object from `require('./lib')`.

`someFunc` is exported as `exports.someFunc` which allows it to be reassigned.

---

So yes, you're exactly right.  Spying (or mocking) like this only works because the ES6 modules are getting transpiled by `babel` into `Node` modules in a way that allows them to be mutated.